# Prestashop Attribut not working

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with prestashop. 
I create my attributs on my product with generator for dimensions, and just for 3 or 4 others options without generator but on same product.

So, the dimension work, but the others options don't work. The price stay the same for "Type de pose" => "sans perçage" normaly, there is a augmentation of 8.33 €. Such, for "GUIDAGE LATÉRAL : " => " AIMANT".

URL : http://dev.netsr.net/s4h/index.php?id_product=20&controller=product

Someone, see why ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess they are not configured properly. You need to add the same number of attribute (and type) to all combinations of a product, otherwise it won't work. Can you screen how they're setup now? Have a look at this vid, it might clarify: http://nemops.com/prestashop-attributes/